# How do I make a google plus button with a custom layout in android?

Tags: android, icons

I want to create a custom layout for my google plus button, any ideas? I've tried calling the OnClickEvent of the google plus button (that doesn't work) and I've tried changing the background image. Source code:

```
           <com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton
            xmlns:plus="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.plus"
            android:id="@+id/plus_one_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            plus:size="standard"
            plus:annotation="inline"/>

    holder.mPlusOneButton = (PlusOneButton) holder.content.findViewById(R.id.plus_one_button);
    holder.mPlusOneButton.initialize("http://www.xxx.xx/", 0);
```

Comment: Sort of resolved: Google says: "You must only use the +1 button in its provided formats. You must not use another image to represent the functionality of a +1 button." -[link](https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/#gapi.plusone.render)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add a custom button to your layout
2. Set `OnClickListener` to your custom button
3. Use the `PlusClient` as described [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started#step_3_initialize_the_plusclient) to handle the login procedure

As example I can provide my controller class for handling Google Plus login:

```
public class GooglePlusLoginController implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    public static final int REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN = 100;

    private PlusClient googlePlusClient;
    private ConnectionResult connectionResult;
    private Activity activity;

    public GooglePlusLoginController(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;


        googlePlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(activity, this, this)
                .setActions("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity")
                .setScopes(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN) // Space separated list of scopes
                .build();
        googlePlusClient.connect();
    }

    // call this method in your click handler
    public void login() {
        try {
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(activity, REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            googlePlusClient.connect();
        }
    }

    // call this method in your activity's onActivityResult
    public void onActivityResult() {
        if(!googlePlusClient.isConnected() && !googlePlusClient.isConnecting()) {
            googlePlusClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        // connected, you can now get user's data from
        // googlePlusClient.getCurrentPerson()
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        connectionResult = result;
    }

    private void logout() {
        if(googlePlusClient.isConnected()) {
            googlePlusClient.clearDefaultAccount();
            googlePlusClient.disconnect();
            googlePlusClient.connect();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry my question was to vague, I meant a Google +1 button.. but I'll give you the right answer anyway;)