# Replace Google Plus login button with custom image in android

Tags: android, google-plus

I'm integrating Google Plus login in my application.
I want to change my login button image with my custom icon.

How to do that?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766224/how-do-i-make-a-google-plus-button-with-a-custom-layout-in-android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its simple, using guideline from [Google+ Sign In](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in), you can use simple Button

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/button"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:text="@string/common_signin_button_text_long" />
```

By setting onClickListener

```
 if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
      Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
      mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
      mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
```

Comment: @CuckooMarianne Here is alternate option to do the same
 http://stackoverflow.com/a/42061877/6676466