# Custom Google Plus One Button In Android

Tags: android, google-plus

How can I use my own Button as a Google Plus One Button in Android.
I don't want to use the background which is given with the library used. I want my custom background. I am using:

```
<com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton
```

instead I want to use:

```
<Button
```

Please Help.
Thanks

Comment: I have already answered similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/29888976/1061944

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain It's google plus login button, I want to replace +1 button which is used to share your url link or use to vote up. https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/recommend

Comment: did you try something ?

Comment: not yet, just going through with the doc, but didn't get anything which I want.

Comment: @Illusion did you find any solution yet?