# Layout Google Sign In Button - Android

Tags: android, layout, google-signin

I'm searching everywhere and not finding what I want, I'm starting to think that this is impossible.

Here's the question: I have a google button for sign in, it's a beautiful button, but it doesn't fit in my layout, I would like to use an image, created by me in the google button, like what happens in the Image Buttons, is that possible? If yes, how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: please share your xml layout

Comment: Yeah you can add your customised button. Please share your xml code

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have your question solution. I tried this always for custom SignIn Button for google plus.

Try this it is tested by me.

Here is the Code.

**xml layout**

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/google_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:text="Text"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

**Method for customisation**

```
private void googleBtnUi() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    SignInButton googleButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.google_button);
    googleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < googleButton.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = googleButton.getChildAt(i);

        if (v instanceof TextView)
        {
            TextView tv = (TextView) v;
            tv.setTextSize(14);
            tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
            tv.setText("My Text");
            tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            tv.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher));
            tv.setSingleLine(true);
            tv.setPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

## Edit

Add this code before return in method `googleBtnUi()`

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = tv.getLayoutParams();
params.width = 100;
params.height = 70;
tv.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Hi, I accepted your anwser, it has worked perfectly. Thanks. I'd like to know if it is possible to make the image adapt to the size of the button. I'm trying an image that is big, I'd like that the image became the size of the button

Comment: Yes you can please see my Edited Answer

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to use Google Sign-In button, if it doesn't fit in your layout. You can simply create your own Button with your own design and in OnClick method just create Google sign in intent.

```
Button myGoogleBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginGoogle);
myGoogleBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
       startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own button and use XML tag `android:drawableLeft="@drawable\file"` to show any image on button.