# How to use GoogleSigninButton?

Tags: android

I want to use the Google login button in LoginActivity.

This code in LoginActivity has an error. What's the problem?

```
 signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((RegisterActivity)RegisterActivity.mContext).googlesign();
        }
    });
//error
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.devkang.instagramtest.RegisterActivity.googlesign()' on a null object reference
    at com.devkang.instagramtest.LoginActivity$3.onClick(LoginActivity.java:108)
```

but this GoogleSignInButton in RegisterActivity works.

```
googlesign();

}

public void googlesign(){
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
     startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);

}
```

Comment: you can not access to googlesign in other activitys

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42059026/layout-google-sign-in-button-android