# Android Studio Google SignIn Button layout problem

Tags: android, android-studio, google-signin

I'm trying to add a Google SignIn button and I've seen that if I want to make my custom one, I need to follow all of the design conditions of google, so I'm trying to use the one avaiable in Android Studio.

[image: The problem is that I can't align "Accedi" after the google logo]

There is no gravity attribute for that button.

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.6"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
    app:flow_horizontalAlign="start"/>
```

Here is my code

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42059026/layout-google-sign-in-button-android

Comment: Can you show the error?

Comment: why you want to make google sign button ?? You can use your custom button too same as google sign in button

Comment: @GumNaam the problem is that the "Accedi" text is not after the google icon but in the center of the View